# Probability question with 4 dice.

Tags: probability, game-theory

> 1) Roll for 4 die. What is the probability of throwing two distinct pairs of dice.

I think I solved this by considering each roll as we have independent events so let $A$ be the event of 2 pairs of distinct pairs
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4)= {3 \choose 2}\cdot\mathbb{P}(A_1)\cdot\mathbb{P}(A_2)\cdot\mathbb{P}(A_3)\cdot\mathbb{P}(A_4)
$$ 
where:

1. $A_1$ is the first roll, so it can be any one of the 6 faces.
2. $A_2$ is the second roll, and has probability $1/6$.
3. $A_3$ can be any number but that of $A_1$ and $A_2$ so has probability $5/6$.
4. $A_4$, like the second roll, can only be one of 6 numbers, so has probability $1/6$.

Since there are 3 choose 2 ways of arranging our rolls, the total probability is
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) = 3\cdot 1 \cdot \frac 1 6 \cdot \frac 5 6 \cdot \frac 1 6 = \frac{5}{72}.
$$
Now more interestingly:

> Generalise this game to multiple rounds. Each round we can remove all the dice, a pair, or no dice and then re-roll the dice we have removed from the game. The game ends when we have 2 pairs of distinct pairs of die. What is the probability that after say, $3$ rounds, we have 2 distinct pairs of die.

Now I assume the optimum strategy is if we don't have two distinct pairs, we remove either 1 pair of unpaired dice if the other two are paired, or we remove all dice. However I'm not sure how to go from here.

Comment: Note that for 4 dice the probability of two pairs should be half what you got. You counted all the favorable outcomes twice.

Comment: Ah yeah since our first dice doesn't count I guess it should be 3 choose 2?

Comment: It should be $\binom{6}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{2}$ variants from $6^4$ total. So - yes, $5/72$, but your reasoning about $3$ choose $2$ is unclear to me.

Comment: As in the first roll does not matter, so we have 3 rolls, wherein the pairings could be (n)(nmm), (n)(mnm), (n)(mmn).

Comment: If you let $D = \{ 1, 2, \dots, 6 \}$ and subsequently $\Omega = \{(a, b) \in D^2 | a \leq b\}$ the chances of rolling a pair would be $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{6}{| \Omega |}$ (there are six possible pairs), two pairs would be $\mathbb{P}(A)^2$ and two distinct pairs would be $\frac{6}{| \Omega |} \frac{5}{| \Omega |} = \frac{30}{| \Omega |^2} = \frac{10}{147}$, not $\frac{5}{72}$. Using a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) is a more reliable and systematic method of approaching such problems.

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie If we roll 2 dice we have $36$ equiprobable variants, not $21$.

Comment: @NCh I think he's right as we're counting stuff twice since $|\Omega|$ is equal to the set $|{(1,1), (1,2), ... , (1,6), (2,2), (2,3), ... (2,6), ... , (5,5), (5,6), (6,6)}|$ which is $6 + 5 + ... + 2 + 1 = 21$.

Comment: @JohnMiller As NCh pointed out, my definition for $\Omega$ is wrong, as the results aren't necessarily according to the $a \leq b$ part. If that is skipped, and we define $\Omega = D^2$, it gives $| \Omega | = 36$ and therefore $\frac{30}{|\Omega|^2} = \frac{5}{216}$, which still isn't equal to $\frac{5}{72}$. If the $a \leq b$ part is taken into account the answer is wrong because the probability of getting two sixes as a result is less than the probability of throwing a $5$ and a $6$.

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie Oh okay yeah that makes sense. That result, 5/216, doesn't take into account combinations though, of which there are 3 so it still stays at 5/72.

Comment: @JohnMiller There's no reason to use permutations. You're throwing two dice at a time, right? That means it goes according to the probability space I described with $\Omega = D^2$, hence the outcome is invariant to which set of dice is thrown first.

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie Idk why I wrote permutations, I meant combinations. And yes it does as we're not throwing 2 die at a time and checking if they match. We throw all 4 die and then pair them respectively. Either (1,2), (3,4) form a pair of pairs, or (1,3), (2,4) or (1,4), (2,3) where the number denotes the dice indice.

Comment: @JohnMiller Ah, yes, that makes sense. However, I then argue that the current description of the question is unclear. In the original problem you said you threw one pair of dice twice, which differs from the solution you subsequently provide, which describes the probability of having thrown two distinct pairs of dice when four individual dice have been thrown.

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie Yeah I cleared it up after I reread the question. But I'm more interested in the second part of the question.

Comment: An observation on the second part: suppose the roll of four dice results in one pair (but not 4-of-a-kind). Keeping just the pair gives a $5/36$ chance of rolling a different pair with the remaining dice. Keeping the pair and one other dice not the same as the pair gives a $1/6 = 6/36$ chance of getting the second pair. So, keeping three dice including the pair is a better strategy than just keeping the pair.

Comment: @nickgard I've worked on this since and come up with a long probability tree. The strategy is as follows: -Two distinct pairs: stop the game -4 of the same: reroll 2 die -3 of the same: reroll one of the same die -1 pair 2 distinct: reroll one of the distinct die -If no pairings, reroll 2 of the die. After working out the conditional probabilities of subsequent rolls I worked out that after 3 rounds you have around a 31.8% chance of 2 distinct pairs.

Comment: Does $1212$ count?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What do you mean?

Comment: @JohnMiller:  If someone rolls a 1 and 2, and next a 1 and 2... is that "two distinct pairs" (i.e., two 1s and two 2s)?  Or must they be $aa$ on the first rolls and $bb$ on the second rolls?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Order doesn't matter so long as there are 2 distinct pairs in a set of 4 die, so (abba), (abab), (aabb) will all count.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part of the question, we have $4$ different states: nothing (the initial state), one pair, one pair and a distinct singleton, and two distinct pairs (the absorbing winning state). Let’s number them $0$ through $3$ in that order. Then the transition matrix is

$$
6^{-4}\pmatrix{
6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3&0&0&0\\
6\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1&6^2\cdot1\cdot1&0&0\\
6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot\binom42+6\cdot5\cdot4&6^2\cdot6\cdot5&6^3\cdot5&0\\
6\cdot5\cdot\binom32&6^2\cdot5&6^3\cdot1&6^4}
=
6^{-3}\pmatrix{
60&0&0&0\\
1&6&0&0\\
140&180&180&0\\
15&30&36&216
}\;.
$$

We can let [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B60%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C6%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B140%2C180%2C180%2C0%7D%2C%7B15%2C30%2C36%2C216%7D%7D%5E3) compute the third power of this matrix:

$$
6^{-7}\pmatrix{
6000&0&0&0\\
111&6&0&0\\
183230&167580&162000&0\\
90595&112350&117936&279936
}\;.
$$

The probability that the absorbing winning state is reached in three rounds from the initial state is the bottom left entry,

$$
\frac{90595}{279936}\approx0.3236\;.
$$

Roughly, you have a $1$ in $3$ chance to get two distinct pairs, a $2$ in $3$ chance to get one pair and a distinct singleton, and a negligible chance to get nothing or only one pair.

Comment: I'm not familiar with probability matrices, could you give some guidance on what you constructed and why? I can kind of make out probabilities from my probability tree but I can't figure out why they're in that order in your matrices.

Comment: @JohnMiller: The matrix element $a_{ij}$ in row $i$ and column $j$ is the probability that if we start in state $j$ we will end up in state $i$. For instance, if we're in state $0$, the probability to go directly to state $3$ is the $6^{-4}\cdot6\cdot5\cdot\binom32$ that you already calculated in the question. The element $a_{20}$ is the probability to get a pair and a distinct singleton from scratch: There are $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot\binom42$ ways to get a pair and two distinct singletons (one of which is retained), and $6\cdot5\cdot4$ ways to get a triple and a distinct singleton.

Comment: Yeah I did some background reading and it makes sense. Thanks for the answer.